# Get the sum of all values a range function has gone through, in a pd dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, range

I have a pd.DataFrame called LoL3:

```
                    T1   T2   T3   T4   T5   T6
Date                                                                          
20200519  19:00:00  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
20200519  19:15:00  1.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
20200519  19:30:00  0.0  NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
20200519  19:45:00  0.0  NaN  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
20200519  20:00:00  -1.0 NaN  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Now I am trying to go through the code using a range function, and for every value in LoL3 (pandas DF), **I would like to know the sum of all previous values, and if the sum is more than 3, the 1 should turn into a 0**.

Just to clarify - the range should iterate row by row, top to bottom.

Expected output:

```
                    T1   T2   T3   T4   T5   T6
Date                                                                          
20200519  19:00:00  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
20200519  19:15:00  1.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
20200519  19:30:00  0.0  NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
20200519  19:45:00  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0* 0.0  0.0
20200519  20:00:00  -1.0 NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0* 0.0
```

*is changed

I tried to do this:

```
for i in range(1, len(LOL3)):
    if LOL3.iloc[:i].sum() <= 3:
        continue
    else:
        LOL3[i] = 0
```

I think a solution is not too far away, any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your expected output.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem correct because the positions at which you are changing the values doesn't seem to follow the logic `if the sum is more than 3, the 1 should turn into a 0.`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, I am trying to iterate row by row, top to bottom. Using this logic, it should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `-1` value, there would be a nice vectorized solution using pandas' `cumsum()` method. But since there is a negative value, and judging by your expected output, the "sum of all previous values" refers to the already updated values and includes the current one, I can't think of a solution without a loop.

So here's the straightforward solution:

```py
# convert the values to a flat array
array = np.array(LoL3).flatten()

# replace values as stated in the question
cumsum = 0
for i, x in enumerate(array):
    if not np.isnan(x):
        if (cumsum + x) > 3:
            array[i] = 0
        else:
            cumsum += x

# convert new values to dataframe
LoL3_new = pd.DataFrame(array.reshape(LoL3.shape), 
                        columns=LoL3.columns,
                        index=LoL3.index)
```

Comment: That's really smart and works like a charm, thanks Arne!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Date` column is the index.

```
for i_row, row in enumerate(LoL3.itertuples(index=False)): # Removes index
    count = 0
    for i_value, value in enumerate(row):
        count += value
        if count > 3:
            LoL3.iloc[i_row][i_value] = 0
```